# delete and start insert

Tags: evil, insert

Coming from vim, I use evil, and I am used typing `s` to replace (substitute) text and continue in insert mode.

In normal mode, `s` is a synonym for `cl`.
In visual mode, `s` is a synonym for `c`.
Both (`cl` and `c`) invoke the function `evil-change`, but with some beginning and end parameter.

I did not manage to rebind the `s` key to the functionalities described. Any ideas?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I want to bind `s` to the functionality of `cl` in normal mode, and to the functionality `c` in visual mode.

Comment: Are you using some Emacs starter distribution? Here, `s` is bound to `evil-substitute` in normal state as well as in visual state. Or do you mean `evil-substitute` invokes `evil-change`?

Comment: `evil-substitute` is the solution, thank you. Mine is set to `evil-snipe-s`, by doom. Thank you!